# Parts of a biconditional

Tags: logic, soft-question, terminology, propositional-calculus

When you have an implication $P\implies Q$, $P$ is called antecedent and $Q$ consequent, if I have a biconditional $P\iff Q$, how is called $P$ and $Q$ there?

Comment: See [Logical biconditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_biconditional)

Comment: I just call them the left side and right side of the biconditional.

Answer (score 0):

First see [my post](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/65024/what-is-the-difference-between-logical-equivalence-and-material-equivalence/72894#72894) on the distinction between logical and material equivalence.

There are no similarly specific terms; usually, *P* is said to be equivalent, or rarely, materially equivalent, to *Q*.

'*Q* is necessary and sufficient for *P*' is not incorrect, however, it is laden with extra-logical interpretation, so I do not prefer it in purely logical context.